# 'Vocab' object has no attribute 'GloVe'

Tags: stanford-nlp, torchtext

```
def load_pretrained_embedding(words, pretrained_vocab_path=None, emb_size=100, type="glove"):
    embed = torch.normal(mean=0, std=1, size=(len(words), emb_size))
    if type == "glove":
        pretrained_vocab = vocab.GloVe(name="6B", dim=100)
        return pretrained_vocab
    else:
        return embed
```

As I import torchtext.vocab as vocab, why can't I use GloVe. This is correct in my local pycharm, but in kaggle notebook, it shows wrong: **'Vocab' object has no attribute 'GloVe'**

The problem has solved, just use import torchtext.vocab and use torchtext.vovab.GloVe can solve the problem.

Comment: are you sure you're using the same version of PyTorch in both environments?

Comment: The version of those is the latest I used

Comment: I have solved this problem, since I don't use the nickname of "torchtext.vocab as vocab", just importing torchtext.vocab, and using torchtext.vovab.GloVe can solve the problem, thank you all the same